# switch/change the cell row place

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to change the cells place after click on it

```
var list = [String]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    selectedRow.contencView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(list.count - 1)
selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(newIndexPath)!

tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When build and run, I get the following error:

> Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to
>   table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and
>   row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if
>   possible.

Comment: Actually the error message says quite clearly what to do. Use code completion to find the required initializer.

Answer (score 1):

As @vadian said error say's clearly , Your issue in the `NSIndexPath:forRow:inSection:` factory method:

```
let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: list.count - 1, inSection: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the contents of array and then reload tableview on didSelectRowAtIndexPath.